# How to catch CLR exception in my code block (C#)

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, clr

Here is my code:

```
private Message SendMessage(ref Message message, string serviceURL)
    {
        Message result = null;

        try
        {
            IRequestChannel channel = null;
            BasicHttpBinding binding = ...;

            using (var cf = new ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>(binding, new EndpointAddress(serviceURL)))
            {
                foreach (OperationDescription op in cf.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
                {
                    op.Behaviors.Remove<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
                }

                cf.Open();
                channel = cf.CreateChannel();
                channel.Open();

                result = channel.Request(message);

                channel.Close();
                cf.Close();
                channel = null;
            }
            binding = null;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError("Error parsing SOAP", ex.Message);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

On line `result = channel.Request(message);`

I get an error posted below in a picture. However, I get it only when I turn "***Break when***" **CLR exceptions occur**. When I don't debug, my code doesn't go to the catch block.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it is not getting caught?  Are you certain your logging is working?

Comment: This exception is generated and handled inside System.Xml.  So your catch clause can never see it.  Common issue with System.Xml, it uses exceptions for flow control.  Whether this is a real problem is hard to judge from the question.

Comment: Problem is not the error, problem is I can't properly catch the error, handle it and log it.

Comment: @HansPassant so I should somehow check if my message contains unparseble values down the call stack before channel.Request(message)?

Comment: hint: look at what `using` means and how it works

Comment: Do you get a different error when not debugging?

Comment: @eisenpony no error while not debugging.

Comment: Then, presumably, there is some other indication something went wrong?
Have you considered that ChannelFactory.Dispose() might be throwing an Exception, clobbering the FormatException?
Have you tried placing a try block around just the sensitive code, inside the using block?

Comment: @eisenpony Yes, I have tried that.

Comment: **What is the behavior, when not debugging, that you think is a problem?** As Hans suggested, it's not clear why the Exception being thrown is a problem for you. It may be frustrating you can't capture that particular error, but it has to do with the way System.Xml was written and doesn't necessarily exclude getting your code to do the right thing.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you try serialize or deserialize string with value = 'X' to bool. I think you should check contract or check your `message` object.

Somewhere inside .net code calls `XmlConvert.ToBoolean(String)` method. Valid values for it `0` or `1` [Link to doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.toboolean(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That's not really an anwser, I know that I try to serialize 'X' string to bool. I also know this fires an error. The question is how can I catch and handle it?
I guess the converter should be somewhere inside Request method so I can't see it.